# Decrypting the phantom payload

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, phantom-wallet

Here is my issue
Been having issues decrypting the phantom payload that comes after connecting with Phantom.

It keeps returning "data is malformed or invalid"

Tried manual decryption and the phantom flutter package but it says the same thing.

I need help on this

Comment: Hey champ, could you please share relevant code snippets and more details on the error reproduction? There are also two Phantom Flutter packages that I know of, which one are you using?

Comment: I am using the phantom_connect and flutter_phantom flutter package


https://carbon.now.sh/yzjxx9sAawkumuhPF6pf

Answer (score 0):

If this issue is still persistent please consider posting on the [Phantom Developer Discussions](https://github.com/orgs/phantom/discussions).